# Django-Child template-Base.html not rendering

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am using the Django template system in my app, and in the child template I reference the {% extends "base.html" %} accordingly, though when redenring the template, it only comes up with the html tags and no css styling-thus not picking up the base.html template altogether.
Please advise on what I am doing wrong?. Could it be an issue with it not finding the location of my base.html template?

This is the child template code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %} 
{% for field in form %}
{{ form }} 
{% endfor %} 
{% endblock %}
```

This is the base.html template code (relevant parts):

```
<div id="content">
<h2>
                Page heading - This is where the functionality goes...
            </h2>
            <FIELDSET><INPUT class=Test value="Test" type=submit></FIELDSET>

            {% block primary %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Please let me know if you need any firther information to solve this issue.

-I will add the views.py this evening (London time)--

*This all all sorted, many thanks for the help*

Thanks

Comment: If you are missing styles (CSS) and those reside in your STATIC folder, this could be the problem.

Comment: Does the base template work (render properly, including CSS) on its own?

Comment: And why are you rendering the same form for each form field?

Comment: Hi Jingo/Josvic-The base templates works fine on its own with the CSS styles- I was thinking I was missing some CSS styles for the child temaplate, would this need to be applied for example to .block content?

Comment: Please show the relevant parts from the base template and the view.

Comment: goliney-this was just an example-I dont think it would have any impact would it..

Comment: Daniel-I have added it to the original question (see above). I will add the view.py file this evening. Please let me know if you spot anything incorrrect..Many Thanks

Comment: Your block names at parent and child template should be the same. So child template could know, what part of parent to fill.

Comment: Tut-Silly me, of course-RE: View.py I havent ammended anything different since I have included a child template-should I do so? Thanks Goliney

Comment: Where is block content in base.html

Answer (score 0):

Like goliney mentioned...
You need to have a part in your base.html file that has

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then you can override that in your other template that extends the base.html template.

Currently in your child template you could do a

```
{% block primary %}
whatever you want here and this would show up where you marked on the base.html template
{% endblock %}
```

Also not sure if you are just putting together a quick example or not.  You will need to create the

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
for loop here
</form>
```